# How to update collection in Firebase using SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, foundation

I'm working on a patient/inventory management software on SwiftUI and I decided to ditch CoreData to go with Firebase. It seems to be less of a hassle but it's still a learning curve for me as a beginner. A dev helped me out initially to create and get the patients on the API patient file, but now that I am trying to update the data, I can't seem to figure out what to write...

I went through multiple tutorials and they all seem to be using the db.collection way of doing things.

Here is my code

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore
class PatientAPI {
    
    func createPatient(firstName: String, lastName: String, address: String, postCode: String, phoneNumber: String, onSuccess: @escaping(_ successMessage: String) -> Void) {
     
        let testPatient = PatientModel.init(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, address: address, postalCode: postCode, phoneNumber: phoneNumber)
       
        
        
        guard let dict = try? testPatient.toDictionary() else {return} /
       
        API.FIRESTORE_COLLECTION_PATIENTS.addDocument(data: dict)
        onSuccess("Done")
    }
    

    
    func getPatients(onSuccess: @escaping(_ patients: [PatientModel]) -> Void, onError: @escaping(_ errorMesage: String) -> Void) {
        
       
        API.FIRESTORE_COLLECTION_PATIENTS.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                onError(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            
            
            guard let snap = snapshot else {return}
            
            var patients = [PatientModel]()
            
            
           
            for document in snap.documents {
                let dict = document.data()
                guard let decodedPatient = try? PatientModel.init(fromDictionary: dict) else {return}
                patients.append(decodedPatient) 
                
            }
            onSuccess(patients) 
        }
    }
 
   
}
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend using Firebase's Codable support, as this will make your code much more readable and maintainable.

For this, your `Patient` should be a `struct` that conforms to `Codable`, like so:

```swift
struct Patient: Identifiable, Codable {
  @DocumentID var id: String?
  var firstName: String
  var lastName: String
  var address: String
  // ...
}
```

Then, to fetch all patients from a collection (or those meeting certain criteria), use Firestore's snapshot listener:

```swift
func fetchData() {
  db.collection("patients").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
    guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
      print("No documents")
      return
    }
      
    self.books = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot -> Patient? in
      return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Patient.self)
    }
  }
}
```

To add new patients, first create a new patient:

```swift
let patient = Patient(firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Appleseed", /* other attributes go here */)
```

And then add it to the collection like this:

```swift
func addPatient(patient: Patient) {
  do {
    let _ = try db.collection("patients").addDocument(from: patient)
  }
  catch {
    print(error)
  }
}
```

More details about this in my [article here](https://peterfriese.dev/swiftui-firebase-codable/).

Comment: I've been following your tutorials actually and if I get this clear, I have an API file which according to what you suggest should be the PatientRepository and the func addPatient which I put in my PatientAPI, I can simply put in my PatientViewModel along with all the functions necessary (delete, update etc).

Comment: So the repository is just a nice way to encapsulate all data access related code in one place. In your view models, you would then use the methods of the repository to access the data in the way your view needs it. Feel free to put together a gist and share w/ me so I can add review your code and answer more detailed questions.

Comment: Absolutely, I’ll get on it ASAP! Many thanks!

Comment: Hi Peter, I follow d your tutorial on books and firebase, extremely helpful and i managed to clean up my code very well. Unfortunately i still can't update the app UI when I add a collection on firestore. Where can I send you my code for you to check as you requested before? Thanks!

Comment: Feel free to create a (private) repo on GitHub and share it with me.

Comment: Hi Peter. I sent you the invite for the repo. My username is FCBHA. Thanks again :)